# Using array.join() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to make a list of every item in an array like that:

```
var prefetch = document.getElementById("pagetitle2");
var array_prefetch = array[1];
prefetch.innerHTML = '<li>' + array_prefetch.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
```

In HTML:

```
<ul class="results" id='pagetitle2'></ul>
```

I also want `array_prefetch` value to be a clickable link, which means I need to add `<a href="">` into every `<li></li>` somehow. However I don't know how to split the tag. Is there a way how to do that?

Comment: Can you add the rest of your code please?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map  Map the elements in the array into a string of an li with a link it in, join all those, and add it to your innerHTML

Comment: Please show a sample of the contents of `array_prefetch` if you want a complete answer. For instance, right now you're just showing the contents as a string. Is it an array of URLs?

Comment: yes, its an array of URLs, sorry @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can add the link like so:

```
prefetch.innerHTML = array_prefetch.map(e => `<li><a href="${e}">${e}</a></li>`);
```

Comment: the array_prefetch value should be the address linked to

Comment: So you want `<a href="array_prefetch[i]">`?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operation first to create the list elements, then joining these together afterwards:

```
prefetch.innerHTML = array_prefetch.map(elem => `<li>${elem}</li>`).join('');
```

This way, it becomes trivial to add your `<a>` to each element.